# Plotyy right y-axis and associated data shifting upwards when enlarging the figure

Tags: matlab, multiple-axes

I used code similar to the `plotyy` function to plot two y variables. However, the righthand side of the graph containing the second y-axis shifts/moves when I alter the size of the figure. This also results in an upward shift in the y variable from the bottom x-axis. This doesn't happen with the left y-axis. How do I lock/prevent the right y-axis and its associated y variable from shifting upwards, away from the base of the x-axis?

```
%Some code

hFig=figure;

%Line 1 (blue line variable)
hl1 = line(x1,y1,'Color',deepskyblue,'LineStyle','-.');
ax1 = gca;
set(ax1,'LineStyle',line_style,'FontSize',axis_font,'XColor',x_color,'YColor',y_color);

%Line 2 (black line variable)
ax2 = axes('Position',get(ax1,'Position'),...
           'XAxisLocation','top',...
           'YAxisLocation','right',...
           'Color','none',...
           'XColor',x_color,'YColor',y_color);
hl2 = line(x2,y2,'Color','k');
set(ax2,'LineStyle',line_style,'FontSize',axis_font,'XColor',x_color,'YColor',y_color,'XTick',[]);
linkaxes([ax1 ax2],'x'); %Links the two x axes

%Save figure 
set(hFig,'Units','inches','Position',[1 1 12 6]); %[x y width height]
saveas = input('enter the filename to save as an image','s');
print(saveas,'-dpng','-r300');
```

Original plot (Note: The original figure was saved manually in Matlab):
[image: before]

After resize (Note: The after resize figure was saved using the code below. This is where we see a shift in the right y-axis):
[image: after]

Comment: I was not able to reproduce the problem. Could you add some before and after images to your question? Some code will also help.

Comment: Here is an example of what happens when I save the image.             Before: https://www.dropbox.com/s/s1bb5fhlppd3vsx/right_yaxis_upwardoffsetbefore.png After: https://www.dropbox.com/s/escvk5ix7pn48gu/%20right_yaxis_upwardoffset.png Note the upward shift in the right y-axis.